# Extract addresses from an embedded Google Maps page

Tags: google-maps

I am looking to extract a list of Caterpillar dealer locations. These locations are publicly available, but you can only access them via an embedded Google Maps page that limits your searches to 50 and imposes some geographic restrictions.

I do not appear to be able to extract a KML file from the embedded map itself.

The site is located here: https://www.cat.com/en_US/support/dealer-locator.html

In the example below, my search for "Japan" includes the 50 sites closest to the center of Japan rather than all of the dealerships in Japan.

Is there a way to extract a list of locations?

[image: image of search for Japan]

Comment: The service which returns the locations takes two parameters, maxResults, and searchDistance.  [I changed the values](https://www.cat.com/content/catdotcom/en_US/support/dealer-locator/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/container/dealerlocator.dealer-locator.html?searchType=location&maxResults=1000&searchDistance=6000&searchValue=-87.40130239999999%2C37.9681771) around to see if their service would even allow different values, and was able to get more than 50 results.  I tried to use outrageous values and nothing returned so there seems to be limitations, but perhaps this gets you closer.

Answer (score 1):

using the url for Japan (the limit is 50 but can be overridden).

> https://www.cat.com/content/catdotcom/en_US/support/dealer-locator/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/container/dealerlocator.dealer-locator.html?searchType=location&maxResults=50&searchDistance=600&productDivId=1%2C6%2C3%2C5%2C4%2C8%2C7%2C2&serviceId=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C12&searchValue=138.252924%2C36.204824&locationType=Digital

will give you (sample only...)

[{"countryCode":"JP","dealerCode":"Nx7JF2FTCugJq8jQ8zhAAg==","dealerId":175,"dealerLocationId":10521,"dealerLocationName":"KOMORO","dealerName":"NIPPON CAT (Japan)","distance":12.66746456566377,"inCountry":true,"inTerritory":true,"isSubDealer":false,"latitude":36.33760452,"locationEmail":"ncd_com-gp@jpncat.com","locationPhone":"81 (026)  722-4320","locationWebSite":"WWW.NIPPONCAT.CO.JP","longitude":138.409729,"parentDealerCode":"eRmnfINsyRQyavZoEq7elg==","siteAddress":"3-1 NISHIBARA","siteAddress1":null,"siteCity":"KOMORO","siteCountry":"Japan","sitePostal":"384-0044","siteState":"NAGANO","stores":[{"dealerCode":"Nx7JF2FTCugJq8jQ8zhAAg==","legalName":"NIPPON CATERPILLAR LLC","marketingName":"日本キャタピラー","phoneNumbers":[{"phoneNumber":"81 0267 23-1118","phoneNumberType":"FAX","phoneNumberTypeId":1},{"phoneNumber":"81 0267 22-4320","phoneNumberType":"GENERAL INFO","phoneNumberTypeId":2}],"productDivisionId":1,"productDivisionType":"Machines","services":[{"serviceId":5,"serviceDesc":"Heavy Rentals"},{"serviceId":3,"serviceDesc":"Sales of Parts"},{"serviceId":4,"serviceDesc":"Sales of Service"},{"serviceId":2,"serviceDesc":"Sales of Used"},{"serviceId":1,"serviceDesc":"Sales of New"}],"storeHoursFri":"0830 - 1730","storeHoursMon":"0830 - 1730","storeHoursSat":"","storeHoursSun":"","storeHoursThu":"0830 - 1730","storeHoursTue":"0830 - 1730","storeHoursWed":"0830 - 1730"},{"dealerCode":"Nx7JF2FTCugJq8jQ8zhAAg==","legalName":"NIPPON CATERPILLAR LLC","marketingName":"日本キャタピラー","phoneNumbers":[{"phoneNumber":"81 0267 23-1118","phoneNumberType":"FAX","phoneNumberTypeId":1},{"phoneNumber":"81 0267 22-4320","phoneNumberType":"GENERAL INFO","phoneNumberTypeId":2}],"productDivisionId":2,"productDivisionType":"The Cat Rental Store","services":[{"serviceId":6,"serviceDesc":"Cat Rental Store"}],"storeHoursFri":"0830 - 1730","storeHoursMon":"0830 - 1730","storeHoursSat":"","storeHoursSun":"","storeHoursThu":"0830 - 1730","storeHoursTue":"0830 - 1730","storeHoursWed":"0830 - 1730"}],"territoryId":175,"topDealerCode":"eRmnfINsyRQyavZoEq7elg==","type":"Branch","ziftId":"W611","ecommerceDealerCode":"W611","ecommerceDealerName":"NIPPON CAT"}

Comment: Hi, sorry to return to this -- how did you find the URL for Japan in the first place?